# change the mongod configuration file after mongodb replicaset started

Tags: mongodb

is there a way to change mongod.conf and have it applied to a mongodb replica set after initialization. I tried restarting mongod passing in new mongod.conf however the new config was was not applied it the replica set still reflected the old mongo config

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/

Comment: It depends , some parameters are replicated from the repliaSet PRIMARY and you cannot change from config file.

Comment: Depends, for example parameter `replication.replSetName` you cannot change. The `storage` parameters you could modify. You man run `db.serverCmdLineOpts()` in order to see what have been loaded.